# In what situation that webworkder's onerror function could be null?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker

I'm trying to use webworker on my frontend project and it's has some problem,the onmessage function works well but the onerror function is null.so I wander what caused that except I set it to null？

```
let DBWorker = null as any;
if (window.Worker) {
  DBWorker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
  DBWorker.onmessage = e => {
    console.log('recive worker message', e);
    switch (e.data.type) {
      case 'WRITE_RESOURCE':
        e.data.status === 'DONE' && (tableWriteStatus.resource = true);
        break;
      case 'WRITE_CASCADE':
        e.data.status === 'DONE' && (tableWriteStatus.cascade = true);
        break;
      default:
        console.log('accept empty');
        break;
    }
    if (tableWriteStatus.resource && tableWriteStatus.cascade) {
      // DBWorker.terminate();
      // 不能关闭，后面切页面或者数据源，还会重新fetch resouce和cascade
    }
  };
  DBWorker.onerror(e => {
    console.log(['ERROR:Line', e.lineno, 'in', e.filename, ':', e.message].join(''));
  });
} else {
  console.log("Your browser doesn't support web workers.");
}
```

got:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPdc2.png)

Comment: **Typo:** `null` is the default value, like any other `on`event IDL attribute registered on an EventTarget: https://jsfiddle.net/0sazvfcj/ You need to set it to a function, not to call it like one. So change `DBWorker.onerror(e => {...` to `DBWorker.onerror = (e) => {...`

Comment: yes you were right.tks